# How to fetch all variation ID's that have a certain name/value

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to fetch all the variation ID's in my store that have a certain name/value.

I have a load of variable products, and some have a variation with a name that contains a string. I need to get the ID's of these variations.

Everything I find online finds the names from ID's, but I need to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coming up with to answer my own question:

```
global $products;
$products = array();

$all_products = wc_get_products(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'type' => 'variable'
));

foreach ($all_products as $product) {
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {
        $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
        $variation_product = wc_get_product($variation_id);
        $variation_you_want_to_search = $variation_product->get_attribute( 'variation-attribute-name' );

        if (strpos($variation_you_want_to_search, 'STRING TO SEARCH FOR') !== false) {
            array_push($products, $variation_id);
        }
    }
}
```